# Prove $n$-th derivative of a real function at $0$ is always $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be defined by
>   $$f(x) = \cases{e^{-\frac1{x^2}} & if $x\ne 0$\\0 & if $x=0$}$$
>   show that $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n\ge 0$.

This is a homework problem of real analysis.

My idea:

1. Use induction to show that the signs of the derivative are different at left and right side of 0.
2. Base case is easy.
3. For k, I find it is hard to find the kth derivative. That's where I am lost.

Hints of other ways are also appreciated.

Comment: For finding the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ derivative, just start writing out the first few derivatives and don't do any simplification (don't multiply together integer coefficients, ...) and you might start to see the pattern.

Comment: You can show by a indution argument that $f^{(k)}(x)=\dfrac{P(x)}{e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}$.

Comment: use the limit definition of the derivative. Use L'Hospital rule and induction.

Comment: Please take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to refresh your MathJax knowledge. Posting images is a killer for search functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that for $x>0$ and $n\geq 0$, $f^{(n)}(x) = \dfrac{P_{2n-2}(x)}{x^{3n}}e^{-1/x^2}$, where $P_k(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$. Use this along with induction to show that $f^{(n+1)}(0) = 0$.